# How can I customize Yesod Login page?

Tags: haskell, authentication, google-oauth, yesod

I implemented Google authentication in my Yesod application.

When I open http://localhost:3000/auth/login I see a page generated by Yesod.

I tried to add login.hamlet to templates folder but it didn't override default login page.

Which is the right way to customize login page in Yesod?

Answer (score 2):

You can override the classes methods listed here https://www.stackage.org/package/yesod-auth

For example if you want to change the default email login page, you can do in Foundation.hs

```hs
instance YesodAuthEmail App where
  ...
  emailLoginHandler = myEmailLoginHandler
```

and then look here to see how to implement it https://www.stackage.org/haddock/nightly-2019-08-26/yesod-auth-1.6.7/src/Yesod.Auth.Email.html#defaultEmailLoginHandler

Comment: Thanks for your help, that is not what I am looking for because I am using Google auth via Yesod.Auth.OAuth2.Google, but it helps understand what should I check for.